# Google Chrome Push Notification throwing error in showNotification method

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, push-notification

error i am getting :`Failed to execute 'showNotification' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': Failed to read the 'actions' property from 'NotificationOptions': Failed to read the 'action' property from 'NotificationAction': Required member is undefined`. Anyone faced similar issue. If so please help me to identify the issue

My code :

````
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('notifications will be displayed here');
    try {
      const message = await event.data.json();
      console.log({message});
      let {title, description, image} = message;
      console.log({message});
      const options = {
        body: 'This is the body of the notification.',
        icon: '',
        actions: [
          {action: 'action-1', title: 'Action 1'},
          {action: 'action-2', title: 'Action 2'},
        ],
      };

      await event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error in notification', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('notification has no message');
  }
});```
````